# How to add attributes to properties using XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to add attributes to properties of a class. I want to store attributes into an XML and read from there. I don't want to add them manually like this,

```
[CategoryIndex("1", "StackPanel")]
[FrameAttribute("abc")]
[PositionAttribute("0","1","0")]
public string Name
{
    get { return m_Name; }
    set { m_Name = value; }
}
```

I want to store all the attributes in an XML file and read from there.. How to proceed ?

Comment: How about adding an example class as well as your example XML output, so people are able to compare/see what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you want to generate the sourcode for the class with the attributes added?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for the amazing [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx).

Excerpt:

You create an ExpandoObject instance as you do with any other .NET object, except that the variable to store the instance is of type dynamic:

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
```

At this point, to add a property to the expando you simply assign it a new value, as below:

```
expando.FirstName = "Dino";
```

The link also includes saving and retrieving the properties to XML files.

Comment: That is so cool. I had no idea dynamic objects like that existed in C#.